# Access Denied to guests

Tags: access, external-users, denied

For some reason when I add a guest to a group they seem unable to access SharePoint. I haven't changed any settings? Why they get access denied screen?

Comment: are they able to access the site if you add the user directly inside the group? Also which version of SharePoint? Are you adding them in o365 groups or sharepoint permission groups?

Answer (score 0):

if external user not accepted invitation and directly open site URL using link they encounter access denied message , first verify that they go through mail link and accepted your invitation.

Answer (score 0):

as [Akshay Dhavale](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/89336/akshay-dhavale) said if the users are outside your SharePoint, it will not work. if the users are within your domain, then double check with your Super Reader and Supper User Accounts in Web Application level.
[SharePoint 2013 Access Denied in Site Collections in Web Application](http://www.get-spnote.com/2018/09/sharepoint-2013-access-denied-in-site.html)